# How to calculate time difference between 2 DateTime fields in SSRS

Tags: datetime, ssrs-2008, datediff

I'm making a report that involves Tours lets say. I have one column populated by the tour_start_time datafield and another populated by tour_end_time. Then i have a column called Total Time. The Total Time column needs to tell me in hh:mm format what the difference between tour_start_time and tour_end_time is. So if tour_start_time returned 5:00 and tour_end_time returned 5:06 then Total Time should be 0:06. I can't seem to get this and the DateDiff stuff I've read all reference Parameters which isn't what I'm using. I need the data in a table. I tried this expression: 
`=DateDiff(minute,Fields!tour_start_time,Fields!tour_end_time)`

But that didn't work and neither did any of the variants of that which I tried. I know im missing something as im new to this so sorry if it's a dumb question but i need someone that can explain it to me or at least give me another function to try.

Answer (score 14):

Assuming your columns are actually **DateTime** data types, your `DateDiff` expression should look like this:

```
=DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, Fields!tour_start_time.Value, Fields!tour_end_time.Value)
```

or

```
=DateDiff("n", Fields!tour_start_time.Value, Fields!tour_end_time.Value)
```

VB.NET `DateDiff` requires a `DateInterval` parameter; you can either specify the enumerator member (`DateInterval.Minute`) or its string representation (i.e. `"n"` for minute).

This will only return an integer value for the difference in minutes; it sounds like you need to then change this to a *HH:mm* string. Off the top of my head the easiest way to do this would be with some custom code in the report which takes this integer value as a parameter and construct the string based on this. Let me know if you need more information for this part.